# STM32 timer encoder mode without overflows

Tags: stm32, nucleo, hal

Can I have timer in encoder mode without overflows in either direction ?
I would like it to count from 0 to max and stay "tapped" on these min/max values instead of overflowing. So if I am rotating clockwise I would like it to stop at say 65535 if it reaches that point. Simple volume gauge control. How can I do this with HAL ?

I am on Nucleo-F401RE using simple rotary switch with A/B connectors.